# FIPS support in xenial

Tags: 16.04, apt, kernel, openssl

I am trying to make one of our jumphost FIPS compliant.
I found this document:https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/documents/security-policies/140sp2888.pdf

in which it says

" To download the FIPS validated version of the module, please contact the Canonical representative for the repository path. "

Now who is that Canonical representative and how to reach him?